# Identifying a user or his order in an IPN dispute notification

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to know how we can identify the user and orders that the user is disputing when an IPN notification for the dispute is received by the IPN listener.

I have gone through the following [dispute resolution variables](https://cms.paypal.com/fr/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id091EBC0E05Z), But I am not sure if additional variables which identify a client such as a clients email address are also set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `parent_txn_id` to find `txn_id` of the order your looking for.

---

Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Dispute Notification and Downloadable Dispute Report.
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf
Goto Page 32.

A Paragraph on the page reads:
The IPN messages for chargebacks resulting from a complaint are asynchronous: the IPN
message for the chargeback can be sent to the merchant before the IPN message relating to the complaint. You should compare the IPN variable parent_txn_id of all IPN messages to match the chargeback with the complaint.

---

NOTE: After notification about a complaint claim, merchants must log in to PayPal to use
the Resolution Center to respond to the case.